# Haskell Gloss: missing dependencies

Tags: haskell, dependencies, ghc, gloss

As uni assignment, I need to enhance a given Haskell framework with certain features. Since this framework uses the Gloss library, I installed Gloss using `cabal install gloss`. This gave me no errors, however, when trying to configure the Setup file of the framework (`runghc Setup configure`), I get the following error message:

```
Configuring lambda-wars-0.1.0.0...
Setup: Encountered missing dependencies:
gloss >=1.8 && <1.10, random ==1.0.*, time >=1.4 && <1.6
```

Trying to install these dependencies (e.g. `cabal install 'gloss >=1.8 && <1.10`) gives me other error messages:

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
next goal: gloss (user goal)
rejecting: gloss-1.10.2.3/installed-3mE..., gloss-1.10.2.3, gloss-1.10.2.2,
gloss-1.10.2.1, gloss-1.10.1.1 (constraint from user target requires >=1.8 &&
<1.10)
trying: gloss-1.9.4.1
next goal: base (dependency of gloss-1.9.4.1)
rejecting: base-4.9.0.0/installed-4.9... (conflict: gloss => base==4.8.*)
rejecting: base-4.9.0.0, base-4.8.2.0, base-4.8.1.0, base-4.8.0.0,
base-4.7.0.2, base-4.7.0.1, base-4.7.0.0, base-4.6.0.1, base-4.6.0.0,
base-4.5.1.0, base-4.5.0.0, base-4.4.1.0, base-4.4.0.0, base-4.3.1.0,
base-4.3.0.0, base-4.2.0.2, base-4.2.0.1, base-4.2.0.0, base-4.1.0.0,
base-4.0.0.0, base-3.0.3.2, base-3.0.3.1 (constraint from non-upgradeable
package requires installed instance)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

After some research, I figured that this means that my GHC is of a different version then what is required for the project. However, I can't seem to figure out how to actually solve this!

I work on Mac OS X version 10.10.5.

Comment: I guess you are using ghc-8.0.x which is requiring/providing base-4.9 - if you want to use base 4.8  you have  to switch to ghc 7.10.3, or you can modify the gloss cabal file to allow base -4.9 or call cabal with `--allow-newer`.

Comment: also don't install libraries like gloss globally, this is just a first step into problems - try using stack instead of cabal. I personally try to compile stuff using stack - and removing all build-depends boundaries in the project I want to compile. Note I would not do that with cabal only!

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Using --allow-newer allowed me to configure the project, however, running it gave me the following error: `lambda-wars[6771:36510] GLUT Fatal Error: pixel format with necessary capabilities not found.` .. Is this also due to the fact that I used cabal instead of stack?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to install it in a Cabal sandbox first:

```
$ cabal sandbox init
$ cabal install LambdaWars
```

But here it looks like you have a version of `base` package that is incompatible with it. Did you try the older GHC 7.8 compiler with `base-4.8`?

Comment: I haven't tried this yet! How can I change the GHC compiler? I downloaded the GHC 7.8.2 package, but I'm not sure what to do next..

Answer (score 1):

- install stack [osx installation docs](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/#mac-os-x)
- then you can use this

> ### stack.yaml
>
> ```
> resolver: lts-7.4 # for ghc 8.0.1
> #resolver: lts-6.22 # for ghc 7.10.3
> packages:
>     - '.'
>
> extra-deps:
> - AC-Angle-1.0
> - AC-Vector-Fancy-2.4.0
>
>
> flags: {}
>
> extra-package-dbs: []
> ```

in addition you need to modify a small bit in `src/Engines.hs`

add `{-# LANGUAGE CPP -#}` on top of the file, delete the `import Data.Label.Pure` in line 26. And change the other `import Data.Label.Pure` to the following

```
#if MIN_VERSION_fclabels(2,0,0) 
import Data.Label 
#else 
import Data.Label.Pure 
#endif
```

I could not test this due to glut not working - but it compiles with ghc-8.0.1, I will file a [pull request](https://github.com/andreyLevushkin/LambdaWars/pull/18) at the [git repo](https://github.com/andreyLevushkin/LambdaWars)

to build lambdawars you need to run

```
> stack build
> stack exec -- LambdaWars
```

Note: on on linux you need something like `sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev` in order to run it.